com.intellij.execution.ExecutionException: Unable to find Windows drive mount point in WSL by path
I have set up IntelliJ Ultimate to work with WSL following the instructions here and here. I have created a project in \\wsl.localhost\Ubuntu\home\me\TomcatBasicDemo, installed the Corretto JDK 17, Maven and Tomcat in Ubuntu, and I use those locations in the SDK and Maven settings and in the Run Configuration. I can open the project in IntelliJ and build it. I can start Tomcat from the command line. But when I start the Tomcat server from the Run Configuration I get different errors.
Firstly, I see

Neither the JAVA_HOME nor the JRE_HOME environment variable is defined

although I have set the environment variables in ~/.bashrc, ~/.profile and /etc/environment.
So I put a line
export JAVA_HOME="/home/me/amazon-corretto-17.0.12.7.1-linux-x64"

at the top of $TOMCAT_HOME/bin/catalina.sh.
This lets me start Tomcat from the run configuration, but now I'm getting the error from the title:

[2024-08-23 09:42:54,913] Artifact TomcatBasicDemo:war exploded:
com.intellij.javaee.oss.admin.jmx.JmxAdminException:
com.intellij.execution.ExecutionException: Unable to find Windows
drive mount point in WSL by path:
'\wsl.localhost\Ubuntu\home\me\TomcatBasicDemo\target\TomcatBasicDemo-1.0-SNAPSHOT'

I've tried a number of different settings in Intellij in order to run a WSL located project in Tomcat, and they all led to this error. What am I missing?
